# Eclipse: Method std::thread.detach() could not be resolved

Tags: cuda, header-files, nsight

I am using the `NSight Eclipse Edition` and some members [here `detach()`] cannot be resolved even the project compiles fine.

The error message appears in version 7.0 and 7.5.

[image]

**UPDATE:** OK; I found out in the include `thread` is in the beginning this check:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
# include <bits/c++0x_warning.h>
#else
```

and because `__cplusplus` is in `Nsight` defined like this:

[image]

therefore the `#if` is parsed and the members are not found - which are defined in the `#else` section.

I cannot set the value in Eclipse because in the `Preprocessor include Paths, Macros etc.` window the buttons are disabled and this note is shown:

[image]

Any idea how to update the `__cplusplus` value?

Comment: have you tried setting c++11 compilation option in nsight eclipse edition?   If that doesn't help you could try `#undef __cplusplus`   and `#define __cplusplus=201103L` right before you include `thread`.  You might want to condition this behavior on the nsight EE editor parsing, I suspect there is a macro defined for that.

Comment: @RobertCrovella 1) c++11 is set; 2) I also defined my own `__cplusplus` value in the source. But this is not really a good solution. I found then in the Eclipse settings a way how to change the value from `199711L` to `201103L` --> This works now like a charm. I wrote regarding this Nvidia guys and wait for their reply. When they confirm my way I will answer this question with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please set _cplusplus to 201103L in "Symbols" tab of "C/C++ General"->"Paths And Symbols" pane, as shown in screenshot below:
[image: Updating __cplusplus define value in Nsight's Path and Symbols pane]

Comment: Yes, this was my solution as I wrote Robert Crovella in one comment in this question. As you wrote me in the email - this is just a workaround until Nvidia will fix it in one of the next releases. In the NSight version 7.5 are another issues. I had to delete the `.metadata` directory and create a totally new project. There were really very strange behavior. Just check my other questions accessible from my profile. PS: the 20114L is a mistake - isn't it? Should be 201103L...